# Moving a 3D object (an arrow) with camera from ARKit

Tags: ios, arkit

I am trying to put a 3D object (a direction arrow) in front of my rear camera, as my camera starts.

Can we do this without ARKit? If yes, can you please direct me to some good reference or help? If ARKit is needed, can you help?

I have an app that gives me degrees to real north for way finding. I am trying to display the direction with arrow (the 3D object).

It might be a noob question, sorry for that but I am new to iOS development and ARKit and it's my university project.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the arrow in the camera, but:

1) ARKit makes it really easy to actually get the camera images.

2) If you didn't use ARKit then the arrow would be fixed / attached to the screen. Even if you get your heading and use it to place the arrow, any small motion of the phone will mean that it won't appear to stay fixed in place. (i.e, the heading tells you where to place the arrow, it doesn't tell the phone how to actually draw it.

3) To get started with ARKit the best approach is just to create a default ARKit app in XCode, and replace the example model they use with your own one.